# How to add PHP code in functions.php wordpress

Tags: php, functions

```
<?php
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
     
    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Hi, how to repace

```
<?php
 $a1 = get_field('fa1', 'option');
 if ($a1) : ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $a1['a1-l']; ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $a1['a1-b']['url'] ); ?>"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

instead of `<div>Ads code goes here</div>` in `functions.php` Wordpress?

Comment: Hi, how to repace <?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?> instead of <div>Ads code goes here</div> in functions.php Wordpress? - can you explain what you want to do and perhaps why?

Comment: Short codes call functions. Meaning, if you edit the theme template, you don't need shortcodes, you can use the actual function the shortcode would call..

Comment: @QStudio tnx, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean?

```php
<?php
//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );
function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {
     
    $ad_code = '<div>'.sewp_381661_get_advert().'</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// function to return ad markup / logic ##
function sewp_381661_get_advert(){

    $a1 = get_field('fa1', 'option');
    $string = ''; // define return var ##
    if ($a1) {

        $string = '<a href="'.$a1['a1-l'].'" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="'.esc_url( $a1['a1-b']['url'] ).'"></a>';

    }

    // return string for echo ##
    return $string;

}
```

Comment: Yeh, it's not totally clear the requirement or purpose, but best guessing as best as I can guess..